# Specify ICU collations as `ENCODING`, `LC_COLLATE`, and `LC_CTYPE` in Postgres 10

Tags: postgresql, collation, postgresql-10, international-components-unicode

Postgres 10 gains the ability to use [*International Components for Unicode (ICU)*](http://site.icu-project.org/) collations rather than depending on host OS implementations. See [*More robust collations with ICU support in PostgreSQL 10*](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/icu-support-postgresql-10/) by Peter Eisentraut.

So how exactly does one specify an ICU collation when creating the database?

I did read a tip in the `CREATE DATABASE` to use `template0` rather than `template1` if `template1` might have been created using encoding and collation other than what you want for your new database. And when using `template0`, you need to enable data connections to override the default.

And I read in Postgres 10 doc page for [*Collation Support*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/collation.html) that:

> und-x-icu (for “undefined”)
>
> ICU “root” collation. Use this to get a reasonable language-agnostic sort order.

So it seems `und-x-icu` might be a good value to use when establishing a new database that will include multi-lingual text. When a certain language is known to focus on a particular language, the `SELECT` command can specify another collation such as German `de-x-icu`. Otherwise, fallback to the default of `und-x-icu`.

So I tried the following SQL to create a database in Postgres 10 Beta 2.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE timepiece_
TEMPLATE 'template0'
ALLOW_CONNECTIONS TRUE
CONNECTION LIMIT -1
ENCODING 'UTF8'
LC_COLLATE 'und-x-icu'
LC_CTYPE 'und-x-icu'
;
```

Fails with an error:

> [42809] ERROR: invalid locale name: "und-x-icu"

So I stuck on an appended `.utf8` as seen in the doc for the old-fashioned collation syntax.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE timepiece_
TEMPLATE 'template0'
ALLOW_CONNECTIONS TRUE
CONNECTION LIMIT -1
ENCODING 'UTF8'
LC_COLLATE 'und-x-icu.utf8'
LC_CTYPE 'und-x-icu.utf8'
;
```

Fails just the same:

> [42809] ERROR: invalid locale name: "und-x-icu.utf8"

Was my Postgres cluster built with ICU libraries? Here is the result of calling [`pg_config`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-pgconfig.html). The last line is `'ICU_LIBS=-L/opt/local/Current/lib -licuuc -licudata -licui18n'`. I guess that means my build includes the ICU libraries but I am not sure.

> /Library/PostgreSQL/10Beta2/bin/pg_config --configure
>
> '--with-icu' '--prefix=/mnt/hgfs/pginstaller.pune/server/staging_cache/osx' '--with-ldap' '--with-openssl' '--with-perl' '--with-python' '--with-tcl' '--with-bonjour' '--with-pam' '--enable-thread-safety' '--with-libxml' '--with-uuid=e2fs' '--with-includes=/opt/local/Current/include/libxml2:/opt/local/Current/include:/opt/local/Current/include/security' '--docdir=/mnt/hgfs/pginstaller.pune/server/staging_cache/osx/doc/postgresql' '--with-libxslt' '--with-libedit-preferred' '--with-gssapi' 'CFLAGS=-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/Current/lib' 'ICU_CFLAGS=-I/opt/local/Current/include' 'ICU_LIBS=-L/opt/local/Current/lib -licuuc -licudata -licui18n'

➠ How does one specify the `ENCODING`, `LC_COLLATE`, and `LC_TYPE` to use the new ICU collations?

➠ What ICU collation names you would suggest for English-oriented databases? For Western European multi-lingual databases?

➠ What are the possible ICU collation names?

Comment: Maybe your binary is not compiled `--with-icu` support?

Comment: @eckes How to verify that build option? I used the installers provided by EnterpriseDB.com rather than compile from source.

Comment: Maybe indirectly? https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20050801224821.GA66940%40winnie.fuhr.org

Comment: @eckes RE: built with ICU libraries, see my edit. Calling `pg_config --configure` results in `'ICU_LIBS=-L/opt/local/Current/lib -licuuc -licudata -licui18n'`. Not sure if that means I have the libraries or not. I posted [another Question asking how to read that result](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/183387/19079).

Comment: Your install is probably fine, the problem is that an ICU collation cannot be specified when creating a database. It's a limitation of the current implementation in PG10. Such collations can only be used in `COLLATE` clauses in queries and column definitions.

Comment: @DanielVérité Is this fact documented? Or should I file a request on the Postgres documentation mailing list? And please post as an Answer so I can accept and close this Question.

Comment: @BasilBourque re: "_What are the possible ICU collation names?_", have you tried `SELECT * FROM pg_collation` ? According to the collation documentation page, they should be listed there.

Comment: @BasilBourque Hi there, I have PostgreSQL 10.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit, on win10 laptop. I just tried this yesterday `CREATE DATABASE test
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    TEMPLATE = template0
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'und-x-icu'
    LC_CTYPE = 'und-x-icu'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;` And it worked. I have not fully tested the database yet, but I thought I should inform you that this executes fine. I can also see the properties in the pgAdmin4 GUI. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 4):

First let's note that at the time of this answer, PostgreSQL 10 in still in beta stage. Some issues about the ICU integration and how it's documented are still under  discussion, and there might be changes before a GA release.

> ➠ How does one specify the ENCODING, LC_COLLATE, and LC_TYPE to use
>   the new ICU collations?

It's not possible currently (and probably not documented well enough, or not clear enough in the error message: when it says *invalid locale name*, it means from the set of locales provided by `libc`).
This is discussed in this thread on the developers mailing list:
[Can ICU be used for a database's default sort order?](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/3366.1498183854%40sss.pgh.pa.us#3366.1498183854@sss.pgh.pa.us)

> ➠ What ICU collation names you would suggest for English-oriented
>   databases? For Western European multi-lingual databases?

It mostly matters if you have specific sort requirements. In this other thread of the mailing-list:
[What users can do with custom ICU collations in Postgres 
10](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAH2-Wz=bcgmk97YaZ3rs4OoCdn1nOco1HCfRGBCOOty0ztnCnA@mail.gmail.com)
some concrete examples are given of ICU collations behaving specially compared to what libc can do.

When not having specific requirements, I think most applications won't care whether they use an ICU collation or a libc `en_US` collation, except for portability. One of the big points of `ICU` is to get exactly the same ordering across all operating systems for a given locale, which is really not the case of `libc`. I guess that the pre-created `en-x-icu` would be fine for general English, and for West-european languages, I'm not sure why any collation would  be better than `und-x-icu`.

As a side-note, it's not a good idea to use any other collation than `C` when you don't really care about the sort rules, because `C` as a collation will outperform any language-aware collation. And `C` is portable across operating systems.

> ➠ What are the possible ICU collation names?

Although `initdb` populates `pg_collation` with a list of pre-defined collations, a complete list would be subject to combinatorial explosion,
as ICU collation names are formed by assembling tags, as listed here:
http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-collation.html#Setting_Options

Currently the doc does not mention explicitly that you can do:

```
CREATE COLLATION mycoll (locale='my-set-of-tags', provider='icu');
```

but I think work is happening right now to improve that in the doc.

Another issue that might be worth pointing out is that there are multiple ICU major versions out there, and the list of pre-defined collations that `initdb` instantiates differs significantly between these versions, especially ICU pre-53 versus post-53. This has been put in evidence in another discussion:
[Crash report for some ICU-52 (debian8) COLLATE and work_mem values](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/f1438ec6-22aa-4029-9a3b-26f79d330e72%40manitou-mail.org#f1438ec6-22aa-4029-9a3b-26f79d330e72@manitou-mail.org)

EDIT: in the next beta or RC, the list of ICU collations created by initdb will change thoroughly , as mentioned in this [discussion](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAH2-Wz%3D76-%2BQ79agwn5SdTGBix5YzJsaJb5d6t1eVnf%3DkOe4KA%40mail.gmail.com#CAH2-Wz=76-+Q79agwn5SdTGBix5YzJsaJb5d6t1eVnf=kOe4KA@mail.gmail.com). The list will made by iterating on ICU locales rather than collations, and as a result the question *"What are the possible ICU collation names?"* will have to be reconsidered with the new values.

Comment: Hey there. I was going to take a crack at the following question that just got posted, but then I found this in my research and thought that you might be better able to answer it: [Does PostgreSQL support ICU collation's options and settings?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/191905/30859).

Comment: @SolomonRutzky: please don't let this stop you from answering, I won't have the time to try anytime soon.