# Was my Postgres cluster built with the ICU libraries available for Postgres 10 and later?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, international-components-unicode

I wonder if my installation of Postgres 10 Beta 2 has been built to include the new [*International Components for Unicode (ICU)*](http://site.icu-project.org/) collations. For background info, see [*More robust collations with ICU support in PostgreSQL 10*](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/icu-support-postgresql-10/) by Peter Eisentraut.

I used the [`pg_config`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-pgconfig.html) utility to detect the build info. When running `pg_config --configure` I get output where the last line is `'ICU_LIBS=-L/opt/local/Current/lib -licuuc -licudata -licui18n'`.

➠ Does this mean I have the ICU libraries installed, or not?

> /Library/PostgreSQL/10Beta2/bin/pg_config --configure
>
> '--with-icu' '--prefix=/mnt/hgfs/pginstaller.pune/server/staging_cache/osx' '--with-ldap' '--with-openssl' '--with-perl' '--with-python' '--with-tcl' '--with-bonjour' '--with-pam' '--enable-thread-safety' '--with-libxml' '--with-uuid=e2fs' '--with-includes=/opt/local/Current/include/libxml2:/opt/local/Current/include:/opt/local/Current/include/security' '--docdir=/mnt/hgfs/pginstaller.pune/server/staging_cache/osx/doc/postgresql' '--with-libxslt' '--with-libedit-preferred' '--with-gssapi' 'CFLAGS=-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/Current/lib' 'ICU_CFLAGS=-I/opt/local/Current/include' 'ICU_LIBS=-L/opt/local/Current/lib -licuuc -licudata -licui18n'

➠ Is there another way to detect if my Postgres has the ICU collations available? Some way via SQL?

When I execute `SELECT * FROM pg_collation ;`, of the 845 locale names listed, 575 end in `-x-icu`. Does that happen only if the ICU libraries are in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean I have the ICU libraries installed, or not?

The configure option that really brings in the library is `--with-icu`. Currently, checking for this one seems the more reliable way to tell whether ICU has been included in the build.

`ICU_CFLAGS` and `ICU_LIBS` are paths that are required only if the library is installed where the compiler does not search by default.

> Does that happen only if the ICU libraries are in place?

It does, but `pg_collation` also has a new [`collprovider`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/catalog-pg-collation.html) field indicating that a collation is from ICU (`i`) or the libc (`c`)